# Default config of GPIO's using device tree - Freescale i.MX6

Tags: config, device, gpio, device-tree

How should default settings to gpio pins be configured device tree - specifically on Freescale imx series.

So far I have only been able to configure gpios using the led interface:

```
gpioinit {
   compatible = "gpio-leds";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    mykpp {
        gpios = <&gpio4 15 1>;
    };
};
```

The above code sets gpio 4 15 to 1 during boot which is what I want. However, I assume there is a better way doing this making this pin show up in sysfs as a general gpio and not a gpio-led

Answer (score 0):

If it's a GPIO, your dts file should show something like:

```
    gpio0: gpio@c00 {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        cell-index = <0>;
        compatible = "fsl,mpc8377-gpio";
        reg = <0xc00 0x100>;
        interrupts = <74 0x8>;
        interrupt-parent = <&ipic>;
        gpio-controller;

        gpio-pin@11 {
            compatible = "fsl,mpc8377-gpio-input";
            active_status = "low";
            gpios = <&gpio0>;
            pin = <11>;
        };
    }
```

This example is taken from MPC8377's dts file. You may want to have a look at /drivers/gpio/gpio-fsl.c

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this recently, but I found that a "pin hog" was the correct and more generic solution.

This is an excellent example here:
[Device Tree dependency between two nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202134/device-tree-dependency-between-two-nodes)

Documentation:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the following DT on a i.MX6 and Buildroot/Busybox, kernel v4.19.169. Here is the DT snippet that makes it work, **BUT** you can't use the pin anymore in user space. Note, by the way, the tricky syntax of the `gpios =` property. That one drove me nuts !

```
&gpio7 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_gpio_en>;

    sysstat@11 {
        gpio-hog;
        gpios = <11 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        output-low;
        line-name = "SYS_STAT";
    };
};

&iomuxc {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_gpios>;

        pinctrl_gpio_en: gpiostatgrp {
            fsl,pins = <
                MX6QDL_PAD_GPIO_16__GPIO7_IO11      0x130b0
            >;
        };
};
```

0x130b0 means : hysteresis, 100K pull-down, PUE=1 (pull-up enable), PKE=1 (keeper enabled). This is enough to drive the pin low, even if the `sysstat@11` is missing. But the pin is still configured as an input.

Check pin config (note the **[used]** string) :

```
# gpioinfo 6 | grep "line  11"                                                  
        line  11:      unnamed   "SYS_STAT"  output  active-high [used]
```

An alternate way would be to delete the `sysstat@11` node to just do the pin muxing and pin configuration. I'm not sure if it's very smart, though.

Yet another option, as the pin is configured as a GPIO by default, is to not alter the DT at all and use a /etc/init.d script instead, with the command `gpioset 6 11=0`. It works too, but it's not as fast as the DT option.

I think I'll go for the last option.